# Recurring payments and update recurring payments profile limitation

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout, recurring-billing

We've integrated "Recurring Payments" using "Express Checkout" method.
But, now our requirement is to update "Recurring Payment Amount" (it should be less than or grater than the previous amount) before the next payment date.
We've checked with the "Express Checkout" but, it has been seen that, it's having limitation on "Update Recurring Profile" method as -

"**For recurring payments with Express Checkout, the payment amount can be increased by no more than 20% every 180 days (starting when the profile is created).**"

So, if we want to overcome with this limitation, by passing variable amounts to "Update Recurring Payment" method.How should we integrate it buy continuing with the same "Express Checkout" or should we go for "*Adaptive Payments*" ?

Please guide us for the same as your reply is very helpful for us to integrate "Recurring Payments" in our system.

Please do the needful.

**Note:** the method with limitation is: **UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile**

Comment: `Please guide us` [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Your question might however fit http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

In recurring payment, you can't pass unlimited variable amount in UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API, you need to obey the 20% limitation.
In your case, you can try reference transaction API which don't have such limitation: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/?mark=reference